# How can I serve a file from the internal storage directory using a content provider in Android application?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

My question is the one indicated in the title, how can I serve a file from the internal storage directory using a content provider in Android application?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good solution at **[Android: Attaching files from internal cache to Gmail](http://stephendnicholas.com/archives/974)**. This allows me to attach files from internal storage to any other application which are not part of our application.

Comment: Initially thanks for your answer but I already knew this tutorial and had it tested. The problem that exists is that not all applications when asking for a file to my app calls "openFile ()" as there are some who call the method "query ()" which is not how to implement since each app requests the ContentProvider some columns in the parameter "projection".
Also another problem arises when I record files in the internal storage since by default these files are only accessible to my application, so that other applications can not access files when retrieved through the ContentProvider

Comment: then what `serve a file from the internal storage directory` mean? how do you want to serve?